# Behavior of the electric field of an incoherent light wave

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields

If I am not mistaken, an incoherent light wave is a light wave made out of waves with random phases: it consist of photons with random phases.

Now I am wondering what we would see if we would somehow measure the electric field of such a light wave. Would the electric field oscillate with ever changing amplitudes and directions, or would there still be some sort of regularity in its behavior?

Comment: you can use the superposition principle if you know the amplitudes,frequency and phase differences between these waves.

Comment: Another consideration is that there is no such thing as perfectly incoherent source, all lights sources have some degree of coherency.

Comment: Imagine ripples caused by rain macroscopically and disturbance at particular place of water surface locally.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the [thermal light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation) is a good example. It is emitted by any object of temperature above absolute zero. Thermal light is a chaotic state, not described by a quantum state but by a diagonal density matrix whose elements describe the probability of different wavelengths, different polarizations, and in general no polarization is preferred, i.e. any polarization is equally probable.

However, I have a comment about your question, "*Would the electric field oscillate with ever changing amplitudes and directions?*". No, it's not true that there is a general electric field, of a certain type of polarization, but it changes direction very rapidly. You won't find such a common organization, you will find chaos.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to measure the electric field of an incoherent light wave, you would observe that the electric field oscillates with ever-changing amplitudes and directions. Incoherent light is composed of a mixture of light waves with random phases, which means that the individual electric fields from different photons will not be synchronized.

The electric field of an incoherent light wave would exhibit random fluctuations in both amplitude and direction. The amplitude of the electric field represents the intensity or brightness of the light wave, while the direction represents the polarization of the light wave.

Due to the random nature of the phases, the electric field vectors of the individual photons would not align or add up coherently. As a result, when you measure the electric field of the incoherent light wave over time, you would observe fluctuations in both the magnitude and direction of the electric field vector.

It's important to note that incoherent light still follows the laws of superposition, meaning that the total electric field is the sum of the electric fields of the individual photons. However, since the phases are random, any constructive or destructive interference that could occur in coherent light is lost in the incoherent case.

Therefore, the behavior of the electric field in an incoherent light wave would lack any regularity or predictable pattern, displaying random fluctuations in amplitude and direction as you measure it over time.